# Saving image from camera to documents directory

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have the following code which launches the camera app and the user can select "use photo". However nothing happens.

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == YES) {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
    }
```

How I can I get an UIimage from this and save it to the photo album. Ideally I'd like to save this to the documents directory and know how to do that part. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
 - (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    UIImage  *image =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData * imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: The camera popup doesn't show up anymore. I used NSDictionary * dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    UIImagePickerController * pict = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    [self imagePickerController:pict didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:dict]; to call the method you supplied me

Comment: Try with replace info with your dictionary name.

Answer (score 3):

```
        -(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)UIPicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *) info
{

 UIImage* originalImage = nil;
    originalImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    if(originalImage==nil)
    {
        originalImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    }
    if(originalImage==nil)
    {
        originalImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerCropRect];
    }



    [addImageOutlet setImage:originalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [self saveBackgroundImageInDocumentDirectory:originalImage];


    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will help you,

```
 //you have to set the delegate which clicking the button of camera

 imagePickerController.delegate = self;


//This Delegate method will call

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    UIImage* selectedImage =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

   NSString *path = [[self pathToPatientPhotoFolder] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"imageName.png"]];

   NSError * error11 = nil;

   [post.getData writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error11];

}



//This method is useful for the get the Documentry path

    - (NSString *)pathToPatientPhotoFolder {
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                            NSUserDomainMask,
                                                                            YES) lastObject];
        NSString *myalbumpath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MYAlbum"];

        // Create the folder if necessary
        BOOL isDir = NO;
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:myalbumpath
                               isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir == NO) {
            [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:myalbumpath
                   withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                    attributes:nil
                                         error:nil];
        }
        return myalbumpath;
    }
```

Enjoy the coding

Comment: I get "use of undeclared identifier for comment and post.

Comment: where did you get the Undeclared identifier.can you please tell me

Comment: I was edited the answer.now you wont face the problem,Please check the answer again

Comment: I had to add the UINavigationControllerDelegate to get in the interface to get it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

addImageOutlet for what type of object

Comment: can u tel m plz  addImageOutlet for what type of object